# How to handle loading error in jquery Tab?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I called `$('#tabs').tabs('load',0)` to load the first tab, and the server return a response of 500 internal error.

I want to know how to receive and handle this error event? I don't see any event related to this.

Comment: what are you loading in the tab?

Comment: just render a html from server. nothing special. I just want to handle this in case there is some error in back-end.

Comment: if you are using an AJAX request inside it, you can catch the error but i dont think you can catch the HTML parsing error at least in the jQuery tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a possibility to add an error event either and as long as you don't want to extend the existing tab functionality, you could have a look at the general error handling event in jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

That's not perfect but could be a way.

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand why this plugin doesn't give the chance to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is annoying that this isn't available as a built in setting to the tabs function, there *is* a way of error handling tabs loaded via ajax without having to use `.ajaxError`. If you `console.log(ui)` in the `beforeLoad` property of the tabs settings, you will see an object called `jqXHR` which reveals the `.fail` function you get on a normal `$.ajax().done().fail()`. You can utilise this to your needs.

```
$(tabname).tabs({
    beforeLoad: function (e, ui) {
        ui.jqXHR.fail(function (e) {
            // Your fail logic
        });
    }
});
```